# SharePoint 2013 Migration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Recently migrated my sharepoint server to the 2013 version. The migration was done from one domain to another. All users were migrated successfully and they can all log in to the site accept the my account which I have a way around and does not disturb me that much. When users log in to the SharePoint it also pops the login window with the old site url asking you to login when cancelled it works fine. How do I get rid of the old site login reference. It is really annoying to the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a custom login page. Go to Central Administration, click on “Manage web applications”, then click your web site.  This will enable the “Authentication Providers” ribbon button.

Click the Authentication Providers ribbon button, and choose the zone that you want to configure. Here you will see where to configure the Sign In Page URL. Check if you have selected "custom sign in page". If this is the case, copy the url as a backup, and change it to default login page.

Now, the problem is, do you have windows authentication and fba? Because maybe you have to reconfigure the whole thing and just leave windows authentication. To do so, follow this guide, is pretty straight forward http://blog.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2010-claims-authentication-windows-auth-change/